# Why not mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I recently used MongoDB for the first time and found it exceptionally easy to use and high-performing. Which leads to my question - why not MongoDB?

Lets say I am implementing a Q & A app. My approach would be to implement the User data in a MySQL database and then use MongoDB for the question and answer storage - one collection storing a question and all responses.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: I like MongoDB. Why not to use it for all of your data?;)

Comment: This is what I am getting it. Is there any downside to me doing that? Why shouldnt I solely use MongoDb? There must be a downside somewhere.

Comment: Honestly, you can probably keep the User Data in MongoDB as well. Frankly, if you wanted to re-build Stack Overflow in MongoDB, it would probably work quite well.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you want to show all answers to a particular question? Or all answers by a particular user? Or how many answers, on average, each customer gets to their questions? If a user deletes their account, do you want to delete all questions and answers they posted? Or just answers? Or just questions?

Comment: mongodb is a really good way to make simple things very complicated, and pay for them more (in terms of bandwidth and RAM)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

MongoDB sounds like a fine application for your problem, but there are plenty of reasons why you would not use it.

MongoDB would not be well suited for applications that need:

1. Multi-Object Transactions: MongoDB only supports ACID transactions for a single document.
2. SQL: SQL is well-known and a lot of people know how to write very complex queries to do lots of things. This knowledge is transferrable across a lot of implementations where MongoDB's queries language are specific to it.
3. Strong ACID guarantees: MongoDB allows for things like inconsistent reads which is fine in some applications, but not in all.
4. Traditional BI: A lot of very powerful tools exist that allow for OLAP and other strong BI applications and those run against traditional SQL database.

Comment: What does "multi-object transactions" mean? They mention not to use mongoDB with that kind of application [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-are-typical-uses-for-mongodb). Then it claims `"MongoDB does not provide ACID transactions."`, is this info about ACID transaction for a single document old?

Comment: "Multi-object" means more than one record. In an ACID SQL DB you can do a transaction and insert multiple things into a single table (or many things in many tables). MongoDB supports "ACID" for only a single document store, not multiple documents in one list or across multiple lists. This is a significant limitation for some problems.

Comment: Regarding 4. Whilst that is correct, to get the best out of OLAP you normally have to build a data warehouse, which is generally a de-normalised strucutre, and you pump data to it from your transactional system using an ETL process. So if you are building a BI system I agree you would not want to use MongoDB (I presume) but that does not prevent you using MongoDB for your transactional data (as the question seems to indicate) and then ETL your documents to an OLAP-designed traditional SQL store for doing your BI analysis against.

Comment: MongoDB currently does *not* support ACID transactions even for a single document, contrary to what its documentation says: https://aphyr.com/posts/322-jepsen-mongodb-stale-reads

Comment: I would disagree with all of these points:
1. MongoDB started supporting Replica Set ACID transactions starting v4.0 (released in 2018) and added support for distributed ACID transactions in v4.2 (released in 2019) 
2. While there is certainly a learning curve with MongoDB Query Language, it is as expressive as SQL - and now with MongoDB Atlas, you can also use Atlas SQL to query MongoDB with SQL queries
3. By default, MongoDB is CP in the CAP theorem - with strong consistency guarantees
4. MongoDB has a BI Connector that can be used to integrate tools such as Tableau, Qlik

Answer (score 37):

MongoDB is a brilliant database and I enjoy using it. That said, it has a few gotchas if you come from the world of SQL.

Apart from ACID and other things that are well documented (and in other answers too), these things have caught us by surprise:

- MongoDB expects you to have memory. **Lots of memory**. If you can't fit your working set in memory, you can forget about it. This is different from most relational DBs which use memory only as cache!
  **To be more specific:** MongoDB uses RAM as primary storage and "swaps" the unneeded parts out to disk (Mongo leaves the decision over which parts get "swapped" to kernel). Traditional RDBMS work the other way around - they use disk as primary storage and use RAM as caching mechanism. So in general MongoDB uses more RAM. This is not a bad thing by itself, but as a consequence *"real"* RAM consumption is difficult to predict, which can lead to serious and unexpected degradation of performance once the working set grows over the (hard to predict) limit.
- **storage does not auto-shrink** when you remove records. The space that is allocated per collection stays allocated until you either `repair` DB or drop the collection. And it is allocated in huge chunks on a DB level (*data files*), which are then allocated to collections when needed (*extents*). That said, inside the collection's allocated space the documents that are removed DO release their space for other documents in the same collection. This is a good explanation of concepts: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals
- as a contrast to SQL which is parsed server-side, in Mongo you pass the data structures to query and CRUD functions. The consequence is that **each driver provides a different syntax**, which is a bit annoying. For instance, PyMongo uses a list of tuples instead of a dictionary (probably because dict in Python does not preserve order of keys) to specify which fields will be returned by `find()`: (to be fair, that was probably the only sane way to do it - but it is a consequence of not using string-based language such as SQL)

  - MongoDB shell: `db.test.find({}, {a:1})`
  - PyMongo: `db.find({}, fields=[(a,1,)]`

This should not be viewed as a criticism of MongoDB - I enjoy using it and it has proven to be a reliable and performant tool. But to use it properly you need to learn about its space management.

Comment: You were the only to nail one of the biggest contraints surrounding MongoDB, the memory requirements. Mongo will continue to work if you don't have enough RAM to store both the data and the indexes for you "working set" all at once, but performance will degrade severely. This is a pretty limiting constraint since it's not hard for a database to quickly outstrip the amount of RAM most computers have.

Comment: @johndodo MongoDB all data does not load into physical RAM, instead it uses virtual memory not RAM for all data, only some data is loaded in RAM, so your 1st argument is not valid. Check this http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals

Comment: @TaimoorChangaiz I know it uses virtual memory, that was my point. Virtual memory still resides in RAM (if you are lucky) or on slower media (if you're not). So when part of it is "swapped" (I use quotes because this is not real swap, but the process and downsides are very similar) you get performance penalty. There is really no way around it really - the difference here is that MongoDB leaves the decision about what to "swap" to kernel while other DBs manage this themselves which **can** be better because DB has more domain knowledge about data.

Comment: But I think that other dbs only load specific query data in RAM and rest will always reside in Virtual memory, while Mongo db will try to load more data than other dbs do. So in that case it will be more efficient than others. What yousay @johndodo bro.

Comment: Starting in MongoDB 3.4, the default WiredTiger (default storage engine for MongoDB) internal cache size is the larger of either: 50% of (RAM - 1 GB), or 256 MB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use

Answer (score 10):

Possible downsides:

1. You work in an organization that has only used SQL relational databases.  You have no approval or support for using a NoSQL database yet.
2. You've never administered a MongoDB cluster; there's a learning curve, as with all technologies.
3. Your data is really relational (e.g., one User has many Questions; a Question has many Answers), and you've overlooked the possibility.

MondoDB is a fine solution, a good alternative for those situations where it applies.  If you can use it, why not?

Comment: My solution to point three is to have a table of Questions that only contains the overview data (who asked it, its title). Each MongoDB collection is named by the id of the question. I particularly like that MongoDB stores JSON documents so rather than pulling out MySQL data, pushing it into a JSON-encoded array and sending it over the wire, I can just pull and send.

Comment: JSON is a plus here.  I'm not arguing against your choice, just answering your wish to hear downsides.

Comment: Regarding 3., MongoDB can have document relationship. Its far easier to query relations in SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the other comments given; deciding on a datastore (SQL or NoSQL) can depend heavily on the replication requirements you have.

MongoDB follows a MySQL-esque master-slave-slave-* (1 master, multiple slaves) configuration. You can ONLY write to the master.

In a geographically distributed system, this can be unacceptable (you need to be able to write to any master and have the servers reconcile).

In those cases servers like Cassandra, Riak, CouchDB will be better in those situations.

All that being said, if MySQL is a good fit for your app and you want to work with NoSQL, Mongo is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 5):

@johndodo on memory usage.
They say on official FAQ page that:

> Does MongoDB require a lot of RAM?
>
> Not necessarily. It’s certainly possible to run MongoDB on a machine
>   with a small amount of free RAM. MongoDB automatically uses all free
>   memory on the machine as its cache. System resource monitors show that
>   MongoDB uses a lot of memory, but it’s usage is dynamic. If another
>   process suddenly needs half the server’s RAM, MongoDB will yield
>   cached memory to the other process.
>
> Technically, the operating system’s virtual memory subsystem manages
>   MongoDB’s memory. This means that MongoDB will use as much free memory
>   as it can, swapping to disk as needed. Deployments with enough memory
>   to fit the application’s working data set in RAM will achieve the best
>   performance.

So I think, the learning curve is the answer. The better you know the tech - the better your system will be.

Comment: I agree, once you know the DB it works perfectly. That was the point of my answer. ;) I have updated my answer to be more specific about RAM constraints.

Comment: Does mongo should be deployed in seperated pyshical machine?

Answer (score 4):

I can't find reason not to put all data, from users info. to q & a in MongoDB, except one practical reason:

In shared hosting environment, its not easy to find a service provider offer MongoDB hosting. Unlike mySql, it become standard of hosting plan.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on several SQL DB based systems and after 3+ years of mongodb(with Rails mongoid driver) I have three main reasons.

- I don't have the need to join tables, so its faster. Most of the time a document contains  all I need, if not, I fetch the related document - again quite fast.
- I fetch the document once then map the array/json to collect data and make operations. So I access to DB less and because mapping/collecting happens on memory its a lot faster. This becomes even more efficent when I use embedded documents.
- I can make clients define their own fields easily and efficiently. It's not worth trying for SQL DB.

Comment: he asked for the disadvantages. not the advantages

Comment: where did he ask for the advantages?

Answer (score 2):

While deciding the database for my project I heard that mongoDB is free then I thought **why not mongoDB?**

Well, Just to be more sure I called the MongoDB Customer Support Team.
There are three different version of MongoDB as per now.

1. Community Server
2. Professional
3. Enterprise

Actually **Community server is free** and other 2 are paid software.

I asked the guy-

> **Where can I use Community Server of mongodb?**

**Below the response I received through Email-**

> **Community Server's** Suggested use is for development environment. For production purpose
>   Enterprise offering is required.

Please be sure before using the version.

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all (unless you are trying to imply that MonogoDB's customer support team are liars trying to trick people into spending money on their product so you should never use it).

Comment: @Quentin I was trying to convey like if you are thinking about MongoDB then choose your version wisely... Wanted to add some more info.. However i got your point. Thank you for your opinion, appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to not use MongoDB for your use case. I would suggest even storing your user information in MongoDB and making it a seamless experience.

The only suggestion I would make regarding the Q&A collection would be this: if one question can in theory have unlimited number of responses, then embedding all the answers to a question in the same document (e.g. in an array called "answers") might lead to an anti-pattern called unbounded arrays, or in general cause the document to go over 16 MB in size, which is the limitation on a document size in MongoDB. It is generally not recommended to have such big documents either as it can cause performance degradation.

I would recommend using the [Subset Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern) or [Extended Reference Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-extended-reference-pattern) for modelling the Q&A collection.

Using the [Subset Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-subset-pattern):
In this case, you can keep your most recent answers, or top voted answers, or whichever answers your queries will most frequently acccess, in the Q&A collection, and offload the rest to another collection called "Answers". In this case, if you wish to retrieve all the answers associated with a question, you would have to use $lookup operator (equivalent to left outer join in SQL), which would be less performant than retrieving the documents embedded in the main collection (i.e. Q&A collection in your case), but the idea here is that the "Answers" collection is rarely or less frequently accessed.

If your use case is relatively small and is only in development mode, I would recommend using the M0 cluster tier on [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/register), which is free for life and takes away the management overhead of deploying and maintaining database clusters. (However, the M0 tier is not suitable for production, and there are [limitations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/) to be aware of)